# What are typical rules for parallel academic appointments?

Tags: joint-appointment

Many universities have *visiting* (also sometimes termed [adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_professor) outside the US) faculty positions for [non-salaried academics associated with a department](https://www.cmu.edu/mcs/people/faculty/resources/handbook/nonsalary.html). My question concerns the cases where faculty members, rather than an adjunct appointment, hold *parallel* appointments at two different universities, perhaps as a [part-time appointment](https://theuniversityfaculty.cornell.edu/the-new-faculty-handbook/3-titles-and-appointments-leaves/3-3-the-appointment-process/3-3-5-part-time-policy/).  What types of rules are there regarding e.g. attendance, affiliation in publications, teaching, PhD supervision, committee membership, access to funding, lecturing responsibilities, and salary for such cases? I'd appreciate pointers to corresponding policies or regulations.

Comment: This probably varies too widely across countries, fields and even individual institutions for us to be able to give you a single answer.

Comment: I'm not looking for a definitive answer, but examples of rules and best practices that could be used to draw up relevant regulations.

Comment: I think that, generally, this should be forbidden unless individual negotiations can demonstrate a benefit to everyone. I can see joint appointments for research as being valuable, especially when grant funded. I think you want to come up with "principles" not regulations to guide such negotiations. You might want to form a faculty committee to vet such requests when they occur.

Comment: The votes to close have me concerned. The question seems to be about proper academic policies affecting faculty. That seems to me to be a proper topic here.

Comment: You need to tell both institutions - they will decide within their needs

Comment: Both institutions know, and there is a legal framework specifically allowing this. What I am trying to see is the scope for drafting more specific policies.

Comment: I wonder who would be the issuer of such rules. Individual universities? I then wonder what the point would be in referring to the rules of other universities except for the two ones you're negotiating with, as such rules would express the needs and values of that particular university.

Comment: This question is too broad.  If you are writing a policy, you should ask a narrow question about what should or should not be in the policy.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis, as long as this is rare, just handle it on a case-by-case basis. Only if it becomes common, does it matter to have regulations in place. By them there will be ample experience on what did work and not to fall back on.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Rules of other universities could offer guidance and best practices for setting policies.

Comment: @vonbrand Handling such issues on a case-by-case basis without clear rules and policies can leave the handling open to challenges.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis The point is that what's "best" will to one hundred percent depend on the involved parties.

Answer (score 0):

> What types of rules are there regarding e.g. attendance,

Contractual: Attendance requirements are defined by employment contracts.

> affiliation in publications,

List both, since you are employed by both. Perhaps order affiliations by who paid for the work, or include an acknowledgement to the institute that funded the research.

> teaching,

Contractual

> PhD supervision,

Your institutes will likely have expectations, either explicit or implicit. You'll have your own expectations.

> committee membership,

Likely institutional expectations, e.g., you must serve on at least one committee.

> access to funding,

Apply using the most favourable institution

> lecturing responsibilities,

I don't understand this point.

> and salary

You can negotiate with each institute.

> I'd appreciate pointers to corresponding policies or regulations.

Institution specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think in practical terms this is mostly decided by the first employer. So you already have an appointment at one university and think about starting a second one at another university. Then you need to check your work contract with the first university and ask them what kind of side job they permit. That is the relevant authority and in general whatever they permit is fine (you can and should negotiate with them).

Apart from that you also have to obey general labour laws, so for example in most european countries you couldn't have 2 full time contracts because total weekly work time is limited. AFAIK the US doesn't have this restriction but there might be others that are relevant.